# Trying to integrate gulp-connect with Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, gulp

Basically i'd like to have my jekyll project watched and when changes occur my browser refreshes to reflect them. My thinking is by integrating [gulp-jekyll](https://github.com/robwierzbowski/generator-jekyllrb) in my workflow, this will do that AND boot up a server too...

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
gutil = require('gulp-util'),
sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
concat = require('gulp-concat'),
notify = require('gulp-notify'),
connect = require('gulp-connect'),
exec = require('gulp-exec'),

livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
lr = require('tiny-lr'),
server = lr();

var jsSources = ['source/assets/js/*.js', 'source/assets/lib/*.js'];
var sassSources = ['source/assets/sass/style.scss'];

    gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src(sassSources)
        .pipe(sass({
            style: 'expanded'
    }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 29 version'))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('source/stylesheets/vendor/min'))
        .pipe(connect.reload())
        .pipe(livereload())
        .pipe(notify({
         message: 'By your command..."styles" command executed'
        }))
    });


    gulp.task('js', function() { 
     return gulp.src(jsSources)
         .pipe(uglify()) 
         .pipe(concat('script.js'))
         .pipe(gulp.dest('source/javascript')) 
         .pipe(connect.reload())
         .pipe(livereload())
         .pipe(notify({
          message: 'By your command..."js" command executed'
     }))  
    });
```

**However this right here is what is causing an error...see below for terminal output.**

```
   gulp.task('server', function() {
      connect(connect.static('_site')).listen(9000);
      console.log('Server running at http://localhost:9000/');
      gulp.watch('source/**', function(event) {
      console.log(event.path + ' ' + event.type + ', rebuilding...')
      gulp.src('').pipe(exec("jekyll build && compass compile")).pipe(livereload());
      });
   });

   gulp.task('watch', function() {
     var server = livereload();
     gulp.watch(jsSources, ['js']); 
     gulp.watch(['source/**'], ['server']);
     gulp.watch(['javascript/script.js'], function(e) {
     server.changed(e.path);
   });

    gulp.watch(sassSources, ['styles']);
    });

    gulp.task('default', ['js', 'styles', 'watch', 'server']);
```

This is the error in the terminal...

```
   [gulp] Starting 'server'...
   [gulp] 'server' errored after 83 μs Object #<Object> has no method 'static'
```

**DISCLAIMER**
I know there is this great [yeoman generator](https://github.com/robwierzbowski/generator-jekyllrb) which already exists. And it seems to do everything I want. Then why torture myself? Well, I actually configured most of my present gulp file myself. And would love to figure it out...